# Suddenly unable to connect to Heroku Postgres externally

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-connection

I have for some time now been (happily) using Heroku Node Dyno with the postgres addon (both free plans)
I have been able to connect to Heroku Postgres from my machine using Pgadmin and during development (from Node) but now I can't anymore.

`Heroku config` gives me:
[image]

Which I copy pasted in node.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
pg.defaults.ssl = true;
var client = new pg.Client('postgres://n****s:pVx***956@ec2-23-21-111-81.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d***');
```

(I know I should be using process.env.DATABASE_URL but proving a point ;-)

```
Heroku logs
```

Shows that the server connects to postgres when running on Heroku (no errors) but running locally I get

[image]

I used to be able to connect via Pgadmin but that doesn't work anymore either.
I think it was in the last month or so that it happened.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It was a firewall issue :(
Windows had enabled it automatically.

Heroku was fast to help me.